# how to trigger focus-out in Ember js component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, focusout

I have created component for text-box,here I faced focusout trigger does not happen. How to trigger the event from the component?

Step 1 created text-box component

**textbox.hbs**

```
{{input
      type=type
      value=amountValue
      placeholder=placeholder
      focus-out=focusouttrigger
}}
```

step 2 in script I have written below code

```js
export default Component.extend({
  amountValue: null,
  didReceiveAttrs: function() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    let amountValue = this.get('amountValue');
    this.setProperties({
      amountValue: this.get('amountValue'),
      type: this.get('type'),
      placeholder: this.get('placeholder'),
      focusOutInput: this.get('focusOutInput')
    });

  },
  actions: {
    focusouttrigger: function() {
      console.log("working");
    }
  }
```

3) **Home page** I added below code in my home page

```
<S2bText
     @type='text'
     @amountValue='1000'
     @placeholder="Enter the Amount"
     @focusOutInput = "focusouttrigger" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things need to change to make this work:

If the action `focusouttrigger` is living *inside* the component that renders the `{{input}}` then you need to pass it to the input with the `{{action}}` helper like so:

```
{{input focus-out=(action "focusouttrigger") }}
```

If you pass the action *into* the component that renders the `{{input}}` then you need to reference it by the name of the attribute (and also use the action helper):

```
<YourComponent @focusOutInput={{action "focusouttrigger"}} />
```

Then when you render the `{{input}}`:

```
{{input focus-out=@focusOutInput }}
```

Here's a twiddle that demonstrates both of these: [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/91b7a2716883bef5b14ed4ee6722ba4f?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.text-component-no-action.hbs) (the focus out actions log to the console)